# How to stop animation when click and return it to the 1st frame?

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a css like this:

```
#turbo_fire {
  transform-box: fill-box;
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: burning;
  animation-duration: .005s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  transform-origin: center center;
}
.burning-pause {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
.burning-run {
  animation-play-state: running;
}
```

Also I have my JS-code which listening to the `ckick` event and toggling between `.burning-pause` and `.burning-run` classes.

The `animation-play-state` prop has only two states, such as `pause` and `running`. So it hasn't any stop anim values.

So the question is how to stop the animftion when `click` and return it to the 1st frame?

Comment: Would it be possible to see this animation in an SO snippet? I could help you better.. or at least have some html..

Comment: Change the animation name? Or only provide the animation name with your run and pause classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no real problem for resetting an animation on first position.
I'm wondering in which kind of confusion you set yourself,
-because this is not a problem,
-and you didn't take any second for answering my comment; even  just a 'no'.

```js
const btn = 
  { Xanim  : document.querySelector('#btn-anim')
  , Xpause : document.querySelector('#btn-pause')
  , Xrun   : document.querySelector('#btn-run')
  , Xreset : document.querySelector('#btn-reset')
  }

setBtnsOff( false,true,true,true );

btn.Xanim.onclick =_=> 
  { 
  bob.classList.add('anim');
  setBtnsOff( true,false,true,false );
  }
btn.Xpause.onclick =_=>
  {
  bob.classList.remove('movin-run'); 
  bob.classList.add('movin-pause');
  setBtnsOff(true,true,false,false);
  }
btn.Xrun.onclick =_=>
  {
  bob.classList.replace('movin-pause','movin-run'); 
  setBtnsOff(true,false,true,false);
  }
btn.Xreset.onclick =_=>
  {
  bob.classList.remove('anim','movin-pause','movin-run');
  setBtnsOff( false,true,true,true );
  }
 
function setBtnsOff( x_anim, x_pause, x_run, x_reset  )
  {
  btn.Xanim .disabled = x_anim;
  btn.Xpause.disabled = x_pause;
  btn.Xrun  .disabled = x_run;
  btn.Xreset.disabled = x_reset;
  }
```

```css
#bob {
  margin  : 20px;
  width         : 100px;
  height        : 100px;
  background    : darkorange;
  border-radius : 50px;
  }
.anim {
  animation-name            : movin;
  animation-duration        : 2s;
  animation-timing-function : linear;
  animation-iteration-count : infinite;
  }
@keyframes movin {
    0% { transform: translateX(0); }
   50% { transform: translateX(300px); }
  100% { transform: translateX(0); }
  }

.movin-pause {
  animation-play-state: paused;
  }
.movin-run {
  animation-play-state: running;
  }

button { width : 5em; }
```

```html
<button id="btn-anim"  > mov it </button>
<button id="btn-pause" > pause  </button>
<button id="btn-run"   > run    </button>
<button id="btn-reset" > reset  </button>

<div id="bob"></div>
```

Comment: That was really simple. Seems I've overworked :)
That  was cause I didn't put the animation in a separate class to toggle it. Now everything works.
Thanks anyway body :)

Comment: Don't worry man. I accepted your answer as a solution of my problem as you asked :)