# How do I make an onclick function to stop an animation and start a new one?

Tags: javascript, animation, onclick

I have currently a rocket animation that moves continuously and I want to make it so that when a button is clicked, the moving animation stops and a new animation starts where the rocket flies straight up and navigates the user back to the home page. However I don't know how to do a onclick function where it stops the current animation and starts the new one. What's the best approach to do that?

HTML

```
<div id='FixedSection'>
      <button id='TextBox'>
        <div class='scene'>
          <div class='rocket'>
            <img id='Rocket' src='rocket.png'>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <p id='PopUpMessage'>
          <strong>Thank you for your submission!</strong>
          <br><br> Your response has been received successfully. We appreciate your participation.
        </p>
        <img src='PopUp.png' id='PopUpButton' onclick="flyRocket()">
        <a href='../Website Codes - Main Page/Main Page.html' class='HyperReference' onclick="flyRocket()">
          <p id='PopUpOption'>
            <strong> Return to home </strong>
          </p>
        </a>
      </button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#Rocket {
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
}

.scene .rocket {
  position: relative;
  animation: animate 0.5s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: translateY(-4px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(4px);
  }
}

.scene .rocket::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -40px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    background: linear-gradient(#00d0ff, transparent);
}

.scene .rocket::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 5;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    background: linear-gradient(#00d0ff, transparent);
    filter: blur(20px);
}
```

Comment: I have "recently" made a sample code to show how to control a basic animation. I think it should be help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77422027/how-to-stop-animation-when-click-and-return-it-to-the-1st-frame/77422852#77422852